# Keras MNIST target vector automatically converted to one-hot?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

When I load the `mnist` dataset from Keras, I get 4 variables -

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

The shape of `x_train` is `(60000, 28, 28)`, which makes sense because it contains 60,000 28x28 pictures

The shape of the `y_train` is just `(60000,)` which shows that it is a one-dimensional vector which contains numeric target labels (0-9).

In order to run digit classification, neural networks generally output a one-hot encoded vector, which would have ten dimensions. I thought I needed to use `to_categorical` to convert the y target from numerical to categorical in order to have the shape output of the neural net match the training samples, which would presumably be `(60000, 10)`.

But in a few examples I've found online, `to_categorical` was never used to reshape the training vector. `y_train.shape` remained `(60000,)` while the neural net's output layer was

```
 model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
```

which outputs a 10-D one-hot vector.

And then they simply trained the model on `y_train` without issue

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

How is this possible? Wouldn't the neural net's output, which would be in the shape `(60000, 10)` be incompatible with `(60000,)`? Or does Keras automatically convert the categorical output to numeric?

**EDIT:** To be extra clear, I know how to one-hot encode it, but my question is why they didn't do that. In the example, the net worked without one-hot encoding the target classes, while the net's output was clearly one-hot encoded.

**EDIT:** Roshin was right. This is simply an effect of using the `sparse_crossentropy` loss, as opposed to categorical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the loss function to

```
loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
```

This will work, and you don't have to change the input data shape

Comment: You're right. But why? What's the difference between categorical and sparse? I know that's been answered before but why would it affect data shape?

Comment: I think this question will answer your doubts : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674847/what-are-the-differences-between-all-these-cross-entropy-losses-in-keras-and-ten

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to one-hot yourself by executing these lines of code:

```
(x_train, l_train), (x_test, l_test) = mnist.load_data()
y_train = np.zeros((l_train.shape[0], l_train.max()+1), dtype=np.float32)
y_train[np.arange(l_train.shape[0]), l_train] = 1
y_test = np.zeros((l_test.shape[0], l_test.max()+1), dtype=np.float32)
y_test[np.arange(l_test.shape[0]), l_test] = 1
```

Comment: I know how to one-hot encode it, but my question is why they didn't do that. In the example, the net worked without one-hot encoding the target classes, while the net's output was clearly one-hot encoded

Comment: May be they trained the model using sparse_categorical_crossentropy instead of categorical_crossentropy. sparse_categorical_crossentropy is used if your target labels are integers to be compared with softmax one-hot outputs